# Multiple Parallels 8 dmg's in my MBA

Tags: macos, install, parallels-desktop, dmg

I use Parallels 8 w/my MBA running Mountain Lion so I can use some Office application.
Today, I noticed I have 4 Parallels related dmg's. Each one is approximately 320MB.

ParallelsDesktopSwitchToMac-8.0.1xxxxxxxxxxx1.dmg

ParallelsDesktopSwitchToMac-8.0.xxxxxxxxxxxx5.dmg

ParallelsDesktopSwitchToMac-8.0.xxxxxxxxxxxx8.dmg

ParallelsDesktopSwitchToMac-8.0.xxxxxxxxxxx17.dmg

Can anyone tell me why there might be four of them? Do they all have separate functions? Once a application is loaded and installed, can't dmg's be trashed?

Thanks-FH

Answer (score 1):

The Parallels DMG files you found are the setup downloaded by Parallels when an update is available for your current version.

You can keep the most recent one if you want a backup of the latest installation (suggested) or you can trash all the DMG and download again the setup DMG from Parallels site when you will need it again.